# Rich Snippet not showing in Google Search result page

Tags: schema.org, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets

About a month ago we implemented Rich Snippets on the product detail pages for our e-commerce site ([example](http://www.superherostuff.com/batman/t-shirts/batman-traditional-symbol-t-shirt.html?itemcd=tsbatsymbol)).

We used the http://schema.org/ syntax for the structured data, as it seems to be the route Google are taking moving forward.

[The data appears to be correct in the Rich Snippet Testing Tool](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.superherostuff.com%2Fbatman%2Ft-shirts%2Fbatman-traditional-symbol-t-shirt.html%3Fitemcd%3Dtsbatsymbol) and the data has started to appear in Google Webmaster Tools.

However the data is still to be seen on the SERP.

We have followed the rich data guide on Google to the letter and still no results. Is this a case of just waiting?

Here is an additional piece of information that is making it all the more puzzling, we initially went with a Microformats implementation and within 24 hours the data started showing up on the SERP. However we moved away from this because the Schema.org approach seemed a better bet.

Comment: So log onto Google Webmaster Tools >> Health >> Fetch as Google and leave the textbox blank, and fetch your entire site.  And use a ping-o-matic or something to have your root domain pinged.

Comment: @Nick your website SERP showing snippiest now, I am having same issue, please share what helped you to solve this problem.

Comment: Related question on [webmasters.se]: [Not able to see structered data in search results even when it looks fine in the Google Structured Data Testing Tool](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/89645/17633)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suppose it is one of the reasons explained in my Wiki post at

http://wiki.goodrelations-vocabulary.org/FFAQ#Why_is_Google_not_showing_rich_snippets_for_my_pages.3F

While that one refers to GoodRelations markup, the situation should be the same for schema.org.

Martin

Quote:

If you have added GoodRelations (manually or via a shop extension module) to your shop and still do not get rich snippets in Google search results, this can have one of the following reasons:

1. **Google has not yet re-crawled your page or pages.** Google dedicates just a limited amount of crawling time to a site, depending on its global relevance. It may be that Google has simply not yet re-indexed your page. Wait 2 - 8 weeks ;-)
2. **The markup is invalid.** Try the Google Validator. If that shows a rich snippet in the preview, you may just have to wait 4 - 12 weeks until Google will notice and white-list your pages. If it does not show a rich snippet, you either do not have valid GoodRelations markup in the page, you are missing properties that Google requires (e.g. gr:validThrough for prices), the price of the item has expired, or you use markup for which Google does not show rich snippets. Currently, Google shows snippets only for products and offers.
3. **Google cannot see that your page changed.** Your XML sitemap (http://example.com/sitemap.xml or similar) does not contain a lastmod attribute or the lastmod attribute was not updated after you added GoodRelations/schema.org. This attribute is important for crawlers to notice which pages need to be reindexed.
4. **Low ranking of your item pages.** Your item pages have a low ranking and what you see in your Google results are category pages or other pages summarizing multiple items. GoodRelations shop extensions add markup only to the "deep" item pages, because those are best for rich snippets. Use the title / product name of one of your products and restrict the Google search to your site with the additional statement site:www.example.com.